# X-cart Form Administration: How to integrate a new Form Field Type

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, x-cart

What I am essentially trying to do is to be able to utilize more Field Types than the very simple 'Text', 'Checkbox' or 'Select' when customizing a form in X-Cart.

Namely, I have custom fields in my User Profile form page (X-cart Admin > Settings > General Settings > User Profiles). The 'Field Type' I'm referring to is visible in this screenshot:

```
http://screencast.com/t/OA7b1UBUVN
```

The type of field I want to add is not simple; it is an complex form of a multi-select dropdown.

But for the purposes of this questions let's keep it simple: What would be the better way to add, for example, a choice for Radio Buttons?

Let me know if you need more clarifications.

Thanks!
Mat

Answer (score 0):

So far, with manual wayfinding into X-Cart's architecture I've been able to figure out the following:

List of field types is defined in:
    admin/user_profiles.php

```
// Field types
$types = array(
    'T' => 'Text',
    'C' => 'Checkbox',
    'S' => "Select box",
```

The form for defining user profiles is built in:
    skin/common_files/admin/main/user_profiles.tpl

The template file that interprets the selected field type is:
   skin/common_files/main/register_additional_info.tpl

```
{if $v.type eq 'T'}
    <input type="text"
[...]
```

In the database, custom fields information is stored in **xcart_register_fields**, and the values for those custom fields are in **xcart_register_fields_values**.

The database is read and written from:
    include/register.php

Written:

```
        if (!empty($additional_values)) {

            foreach ($additional_values as $k => $v) {

                func_array2insert(

                    'register_field_values',

                    array(  [...]
```

Read:

```
[Not sure yet]
```